# Perl and Moose: What Moose-based package should I use as replacement for MooseX::Method

Tags: perl, moose

To my dismay I noticed that [`MooseX::Method`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MooseX-Method/lib/MooseX/Method.pm) is no longer maintained and deprecated.

The package [`MooseX-Method-Signatures`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MooseX-Method-Signatures/lib/MooseX/Method/Signatures.pm) is advertized as replacement, but its documentation says: *This is ALPHA SOFTWARE. Use at your own risk. Features may change.*

<whine>What should I do </whine>

Comment: You might find answers and comments for this related question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322181/are-moosexdeclare-and-moosexmethodsignatures-production-ready

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`MooseX::Declare`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MooseX-Declare/lib/MooseX/Declare.pm) instead:

```
use MooseX::Declare;

class Foo {
    has foo => (isa => "Str", is => "rw", default => "foo");

    method bar (Str $bar = "bar") {
        print $self->foo, " says $bar\n";
    }
}

Foo->new->bar;
```

Comment: MooseX::Declare uses MooseX::Method::Signatures internally for method handling.

Comment: thanks! Let me try it .. the docs look very ok! I'm sure I'll have to fight that "class { .. }", I will my miss place my use-s often!